# vsftpd on debian

Tags: debian, vsftpd

After installing vsftpd on debian wheezy based on tutorials I have been switching off anonymous enabled, but before telneting port 21 response OK, checking again on anonymous off the availability of port 21 
with `netstat -tulpn | grep :21`
I'm getting `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`. Where to configure how to enable port 21 ?